# How can I maximize revenue given a distribution of order totals?

Tags: r, modeling, optimization

I need help with a statistical modeling problem in R. I want to determine the optimal shipping policy (i.e. free shipping minimum and standard ship rate) to maximize revenue for an e-commerce site. I’ve determined the distribution of order totals (lognorm), but I’m unclear on how to write the revenue function to optimize with the optim function.

How can I use the probability density function for lognorm to model profit? Is revenue equal to the integral of {the PDF multiplied by order total and the number of orders} - and if so, can someone explain that?

[Edit] I can run some tests to determine how a couple different shipping policies change order totals - e.g. order totals under 29.99 USD minimum free shipping threshold and 5.99 USD standard shipping rate amounted to 5000 USD, but under 49.99 and 3.99 order totals amounted to 6000 USD. How could I use that information to inform the model?

Comment: You don't describe enough information to obtain an answer. This problem requires information about how charging shipping *can change* order amounts.  Do you have such information?  In what form is it?

Comment: I can run some tests to determine how a couple different shipping policies change order totals - e.g. order totals under 29.99 USD minimum free shipping threshold and 5.99 USD standard shipping rate amounted to 5000 USD, but under 49.99 and 3.99 order totals amounted to 6000 USD. How could I use that information to inform the model?